# Internationalization with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make an app with multiple languages.

I did what the documentation says but it does not work.

this my code.

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vuetify from './Vuetify/vuetify';
import en from './Vuetify/Lang/en/en.ts';
import es from './Vuetify/Lang/es/es.ts';
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
   lang: {
       locales: {
           es,
           en,
       },
       current: 'es'
   }
})
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: {
       "vue-landing": require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'),
   },
   created() {
       this.$vuetify.lang.current = 'es'
   },
 }).$mount('#app');
```

In my component

```
<template>
    <v-content>
      {{ $vuetify.t('noDataText') }}
    </v-content>
</template>
```

Everything compiles normal without errors, but it does not translate anything. the results are always what I write within the function.

In this case what appears is

noDataText

Comment: Does it work for you if you set the language to English?`this.$vuetify.lang.current = 'en'`

Comment: It does not work but use i18n outside the instance and it worked

Answer (score 6):

Not sure, which version of `vuetify.js` you are using, but Spanish locale was added, as per this [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/5616), in version 1.4.0 which is **not yet released**, may be that is the issue.

**Update:**

There is an error in vuetify translation document as logged in [this issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4548), change your template to:

```
<template>
    <v-content>
      {{ $vuetify.t('$vuetify.noDataText') }}
    </v-content>
</template>
```

and it will fix your issue.

[Online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-vuetify-starter-9iuzbw).

Comment: @C-Jay do you see any error in the console? Do you have defined `noDataText` key in default exported object in file `en.ts`?

Comment: No error. The `en.ts` is the same as described here: [Vuetify internationalization](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/internationalization#create-translation)

Comment: Wonderful, it works! @ali.turan you should mark this solution as correct.

Answer (score 3):

i find a method inside the **`lang`** object is the **`translator`**
this work for me.

for example:

```
 {{$vuetify.lang.translator("enter key set in locales property")}}
```

translate to your current locale.

> Do not forget to import locales you need.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use vue-i18n instead of what are u trying to do. I am using vue at work for enterprise projects and I can suggest you to use it. Here you an check docs [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/installation.html). I am happy to answer your other questions if you have any about vue and it's plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Change template to:

```
    <template>
        <v-content>
          {{ $vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.noDataText') }}
        </v-content>
    </template>
```