# How can I install translation on vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, translation, vuetify.js

Where is the script to install translation on the vuetify?

I check this : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization, but i don't find it

I find some reference, it like this : `npm install vue-i18n`
and some reference like this : `vue create vue-internationalization`

and if I see on the documentation, it seems that there are 2 options for doing that

which option is the best and how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452496/internationalization-with-vuetify

Comment: @RenatoManalili I have read that before. what I'm asking is how to install it

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to add a new library vue-i18n for internationalization, you can add a plugin in vuetify to get it done.

vue-i18n can be used if you need granule control and additional features over basic options

> Its pretty straight forward, just create a new file in this path
>   src/plugins/vuetify.js   and set up the configuration with atleast 2
>   languages and you can update the current language using

```
this.$vuetify.lang.current = "selected language"
```